# Error tensorflow 2.3 : the variable was uninitialized. Container localhost does not exist

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I m using tensorflow 2.3.0 and
I have the following error

FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist.

```
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
with graph.as_default():
    batch_size = 1000
    features = 1
    alpha = 0.50
    time_steps = paths_train.shape[0]
    nodes = [62,46,46,1]
    name='rnn_050'
    S_t_input = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, [time_steps, batch_size, features])
    K = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, batch_size)
    alpha = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32)
    S_T = S_t_input[-1,:,0]
    dS = S_t_input[1:, :, 0] - S_t_input[0:-1, :, 0]
    S_t = tf.unstack(S_t_input[:-1, :,:], axis=0)

    lstm = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(n) for n in nodes])
    strategy, state = tf.compat.v1.nn.static_rnn(lstm, S_t, initial_state=lstm.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32), dtype=tf.float32)
    strategy = tf.reshape(strategy, (time_steps-1, batch_size))
    option = tf.maximum(S_T-K, 0)
    Hedging_PnL = - option + tf.reduce_sum(dS*strategy, axis=0)
    Hedging_PnL_Paths = - option + dS*strategy
        # Calculate the CVaR for a given confidence level alpha
        # Take the 1-alpha largest losses (top 1-alpha negative PnLs) and calculate the mean
    CVaR, idx = tf.nn.top_k(-Hedging_PnL, tf.cast((1-alpha)*batch_size, tf.int32))
    CVaR = tf.reduce_mean(CVaR)
    train = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(CVaR)
    saver = tf.compat.v1.train.Saver()
    modelname = name

    sample_size = paths_train.shape[1]
    batch_size= batch_size
    idx = np.arange(sample_size)
    start = dt.datetime.now()
    epochs = 101
    strikes = np.ones(paths_train.shape[1])*100
    riskaversion = 0.99 # alpha
    for epoch in range(epochs):
            # Save the hedging Pnl for each batch      
        pnls = []
        strategies = []
        np.random.shuffle(idx)
        for i in range(int(sample_size/batch_size)):
            indices = idx[i*batch_size : (i+1)*batch_size]
            batch = paths_train[:,indices,:]
            with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
                _, pnl, strategy = sess.run([train, Hedging_PnL, strategy], {S_t_input: batch,K : strikes[indices],alpha: riskaversion})
                pnls.append(pnl)
                strategies.append(strategy)
        CVaR = np.mean(-np.sort(np.concatenate(pnls))[:int((1-riskaversion)*sample_size)])
```

Full Error :

```
FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/kernel)
     [[{{node rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/kernel/Read/ReadVariableOp}}]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

FailedPreconditionError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py in _do_call(self, fn, *args)
   1382                     '\nsession_config.graph_options.rewrite_options.'
   1383                     'disable_meta_optimizer = True')
-> 1384       raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
   1385 
   1386   def _extend_graph(self):

FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/kernel)
     [[node rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/kernel/Read/ReadVariableOp (defined at <ipython-input-11-60d6e5975cd9>:18) ]]
```

Does any one know how to solve the problem pls ?